# Query All Users from Different Devices - Android Studio Room Database

Tags: android, search, android-room

I have 2 phones: Phone A and Phone B. Each Phone has a SEARCH that can query all users that sign up on said phone. I want my SEARCH to query all entries from PHONE A and Phone B not just Phone A. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Room database is local database so you can't fetch data from other devices. You need backend for this(like firebase/your own server)

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I have firebase as apart of my app too but not the firebase database.

Comment: Can Content Providers do the same thing?

Comment: No Content Providers are also like local database

Comment: What is best practice to use besides Firebase?

Comment: Go through https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start